# What is the best way to override Rails ActiveRecord destroy behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an application where I would like to override the behavior of destroy for many of my models. The use case is that users may have a legitimate need to delete a particular record, but actually deleting the row from the database would destroy referential integrity that affects other related models. For example, a user of the system may want to delete a customer with whom they no longer do business, but transactions with that customer need to be maintained.

It seems I have at least two options:

1. Duplicate data into the necessarily models effectively denormalizing my data model so that deleted records won't affect related data.
2. Override the "destroy" behavior of ActiveRecord to do something like set a flag indicating the user "deleted" the record and use this flag to hide the record.

Am I missing a better way?

Option 1 seems like a horrible idea to me, though I'd love to hear arguments to the contrary.

Option 2 seems somewhat Rails-ish but I'm wondering the best way to handle it. Should I create my own parent class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, override the destroy method there, then inherit from that class in the models where I want this behavior? Should I also override finder behavior so records marked as deleted aren't returned by default?

If I did this, how would I handle dynamic finders? What about named scopes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're not actually interested in seeing those records again, but only care that the children still exist when the parent is destroyed, the job is simple: add `:dependent => :nullify` to the `has_many` call to set references to the parent to `NULL` automatically upon destruction, and teach the view to deal with that reference being missing. However, this only works if you're okay with not ever seeing the row again, i.e. viewing those transactions shows "[NO LONGER EXISTS]" under company name.

If you *do* want to see that data again, it sounds like what you want has nothing to do with actually *destroying* records, which means that you will never need to refer to them again. Hiding seems to be the way to go.

Instead of overriding destroy, since you're not actually destroying the record, it seems significantly simpler to put your behavior in a `hide` method that triggers a flag, as you suggested.

From there, whenever you want to list these records and only include visible records, one simple solution is to include a `visible` scope that doesn't include hidden records, and not include it when you want to find that specific, hidden record again. Another path is to use `default_scope` to hide hidden records and use `Model.with_exclusive_scope { find(id) }` to pull up a hidden record, but I'd recommend against it, since it could be a serious gotcha for an incoming developer, and fundamentally changes what `Model.all` returns to not at all reflect what the method call suggests.

I understand the desire to make the controllers look like they're doing things the Rails way, but when you're not *really* doing things the Rails way, it's best to be explicit about it, especially when it's really not that much of a pain to do so.

Comment: Thanks Matchu. You're correct, I _do_ need to use the data again, so nullify isn't what I'm looking for. While the simplicity of Ryan's plugin mentioned in his answer is appealing, your argument for being explicit about the behavior persuaded me. I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote [a plugin for this exact purpose](http://github.com/radar/paranoia), called paranoia. I "borrowed" the idea from [acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_paranoid) and basically re-wrote AAP using much less code.

When you call `destroy` on a record, it doesn't actually delete it. Instead, it will set a `deleted_at` column in your database to the current time.

The README on the GitHub page should be helpful for installation & usage. If it isn't, then let me know and I'll see if I can fix that for you.