# Using around_destroy to do an update instead of a delete on the database in Rails 3

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, callback

I've got a database model with a couple of tables that look like this:

```
date       value_1 value_2 value_3
----------------------------------
-infinity  5       6       7
12-01-2012 4       6       7
15-01-2012 4       7       8
16-01-2012 7       7       8
```

In the application, the data is (mostly) used as seperate values; the distinct values in the columns are important:

```
date       value_1 date       value_2 date       value_3
------------------ ------------------ ------------------
-infinity  5       -infinity  6       -infinity  7
12-01-2012 4       15-01-2012 7       15-01-2012 8
16-01-2012 7
```

This design brings some problems: I cannot just "insert, "update" and "delete" some value for the `value_2` psuedo-table, as this may affect the values in the other columns: if I delete the `value_2` for 15-01-2012, deleting the entire record will modify both `value_2` and `value_3` psuedo-table.

The obvious solution for this problem (to me) is the use of callbacks to enhance the create, update and destroy actions with the correct behaviour, using the `around_` callbacks. I've created a class for these callbacks:

```
class TemporalCallbacks
    def self.around_destroy(record)
        # modify the record: replace it with the values from the previous entry
        ...
        # do an update instead of the destroy
        record.save
        record.logger.debug "end of destroy callback"
    end

    def self.around_update(record)
       ...
    end
end

class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base

    ...

    around_update TemporalCallbacks
    around_destroy TemporalCallbacks

    ...

end
```

Using this method, my controller can be very clean, as the business logic knows nothing of this database model. My models can also be clean, as the callbacks can be used on multiple models. The controller:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @some_model = SomeModel.find(params[:id])
    @some_model.destroy
    logger.debug "destroyed!"

    # respond to the end user
    ...
  end

end
```

Unfortunately, the transaction is rolled back after the around_destroy callback, as shown in the logs:

```
... some successful sql update queries
end of destroy callback
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
destroyed!
```

I've tried to empty the around_destroy callback, but this results in the same behaviour: a rollback is triggered, somewhere after the around_destroy callback.

Why is this rollback triggered and how can I fix this?

I really want to solve this design issue using callbacks: it would save a lot of work if I don't have to build an update-instead-of-destroy in all my models / controllers. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured this out. I'll leave the other answer as it works too but doesn't really answer your question directly.

You must yield in the around_destroy method, and you must also change the destroy behavior of the model to not call delete if you don't want to delete the record.

There are 2 ways to use around_destroy:

(1) Use a class:

```
class TemporalCallbacks
  def self.around_destroy(model)
    puts "TemporalCallbacks::around_destroy"
    yield model
  end
end

class SomeModel
  around_destroy TemporalCallbacks
end
```

(2) Use a local method in the model

```
class SomeModel
  around_destroy :do_something

  def do_something
    puts "do_something"
    yield
  end
end
```

With either solution you also need to change the destroy method in the model if you don't want to delete the record:

```
class SomeModel
  def destroy
    _run_destroy_callbacks { puts "do nothing" }
  end
```

Ordinarily destroy does this:

```
def destroy
  _run_destroy_callbacks { delete }
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an around_destroy callback to a model, you need to yield, which yields to the before_ and after_ callbacks, and the destroy method itself. With before_ and after_, you don't need to yield. When you add this to your model:

```
around_destroy { puts "in around"; yield; puts "out around" }
before_destroy { puts "before" }
after_destroy { puts "after" }

$ model.destroy
=> before
=> in around
=> (actual destroy happens here)
=> out around
=> after
```

To change the actual destroy/delete behavior of a model, take a look at [Paranoid](https://github.com/radar/paranoia), which archives records instead of destroying them.

You could do something like paranoid does to change the destroy & delete behaviors:

```
def destroy
  _run_destroy_callbacks { delete }
end

def delete    
  self.update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.now) if !deleted? && persisted?
  freeze
end
```

Here's an even simpler option: https://gist.github.com/1474640/3571c53159d3b3ae3506d4e625e7cd8fb5e3f9d6

Also, see this question: [What is the best way to override Rails ActiveRecord destroy behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236211/what-is-the-best-way-to-override-rails-activerecord-destroy-behavior)

Comment: Do you have any idea why this choice was made? The create and update behaviour can be changed completely with the described method, which enables me to make the models aware of my somewhat strange view on the data: around_create completely changes the create behaviour. Why did the developers place around_destroy after after_destroy and why doesn't around_destroy have the same (replacing) behaviour?

Comment: Actually you're right - around_destroy does replace the destroy behavior. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Can I put the model in this 'destroyed' state, without doing the destroy on the database? If this is possible, it would be a solution to my problem.

Comment: I could not put a model in a destroyed state using an around_filter. Overriding the model's destroy method allowed me to have an around_filter, like this: https://gist.github.com/1689947